# How can I fill empty spaces in a bmatrix Latex like this?

Tags: matrices

What I've tried:

```
\begin{gather}
\label{eq:anm_inspecao_exemplo1}
\begin{matrix} 
    \textcolor{blue}{1} \\
    \textcolor{blue}{2} \\
    \textcolor{blue}{3} \\
    \textcolor{blue}{4} \\
    \textcolor{blue}{BCE} &
\end{matrix}
\putunder{
    \begin{bmatrix}[cccc:c]
        \rule{0in}{.16in} &   &   &   & \\
        &   &   &   & \\
        &   &   &   & \\
        &   &   &   & \\
        \\[-3ex] \hdashline
        &  &  &  & \\
    \end{bmatrix}
}{
    \begin{matrix}
        \textcolor{red}{A}
    \end{matrix}
}
.
\putunder{
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        V_1\\
        V_2 \\
        V_3 \\
        V_4 \\
        \\[-3ex] \hdashline
        I_V \\
    \end{bmatrix}
}{
    \begin{matrix} 
        \textcolor{red}{VI_X}
    \end{matrix}
}
=
\putunder{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \\
        \\
        \\
        \\
        \\[-3ex] \hdashline
         \\
    \end{bmatrix}
}{
    \begin{matrix} 
        \textcolor{red}{IV}
    \end{matrix}
}
```

\end{gather}

What I got with the code above:[image]

I just want a matrix in a normal size, not with a crushed width. But it needs to be empty, without values, like this one:

[image]

Comment: One way would be to use `\phantom{xx}` (where `xx` is the approriate sized content represenitng the amount of space required) for each entry of the matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you can do with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I ,
       command = hdashedline ,
       tikz = dashed ,
       total-width = 1mm 
     }
  }

$\begin{NiceArray}{rccccIcccccc}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & I_V &       &      & & \hspace*{2mm}  &  \\
1 &   &   &   &   &     &       & V_1  &   &    \\
2 &   &   &   &   &     &       & V_2  &   &    \\
3 &   &   &   &   &     & \cdot & V_3  & = &    \\
4 &   &   &   &   &     &       & V_4  &   &    \\
\hdashedline
\text{BCE V}  &   &   &   &   &     & & I_V  & &    \\
  & \Block{1-4}{A} &   &   &   &     & & VI_x & & IV \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{2-2}{6-6}]
  \SubMatrix[{2-8}{6-8}]
  \SubMatrix[{2-10}{6-10}]
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks ! I worked very well! I'm just trying to set a \label{eq:xyz} for this now. I've tried to do in the same way that I've done in my example with bmatrix but it didn't work. Could you help me with this?

Comment: `\[.... \label{eq:xyz}\]` as usual with equations...